# Create a side panel using Html and CSS (or JavaScript) which can resize

Tags: javascript, html, css

May I know what is the best way to have a fixed height side panel (usually 100% of View Height), but the width is resizable by the user?

I do not want an (HTML) split view, which shares the view area between two panels.

I wish the side panel when extended would overlap the content below it.

I have searched for two days and can't find any similar example.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important parts are:

1. Fix the position of the Panel
2. Increase the z-index so it's over your other content
3. Add a mosemove event listener for dragging

Sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
      #side-panel {
        /* important */
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        /* just style */
        background-color: aliceblue;
        padding-left: 15px;
      }

      #side-drag {
        /* important */
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        /* just style */
        width: 15px;
        background-color: aqua;
        cursor: e-resize;
      }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <!-- Normal content -->

        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.   

Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.   

Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.   

At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, At accusam aliquyam diam diam dolore dolores duo eirmod eos erat, et nonumy sed tempor et et invidunt justo labore Stet clita ea et gubergren, kasd magna no rebum. sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua. est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.   

Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus.   

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.   

Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.   

Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    </div>



    <div id="side-panel">
        <div id="side-drag">
            
        </div>
        Hallo
    </div>


    <script>
        const panel = document.getElementById("side-panel")
        const resizer = document.getElementById("side-drag")
        
        resizer.addEventListener('mousedown', initResize, false);

        //Window funtion mousemove & mouseup
        function initResize(e) {
            window.addEventListener('mousemove', Resize, false);
            window.addEventListener('mouseup', stopResize, false);
        }
        //on mouseup remove windows functions mousemove & mouseup
        function stopResize(e) {
            window.removeEventListener('mousemove', Resize, false);
            window.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopResize, false);
        }

        //resize the element
        function Resize(e) {
            
            panel.style.width = (window.innerWidth - e.clientX  ) + 'px';
        
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Niro, I was hoping we have an existing widget or library which can do a panel like this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use '`position:absolute;top:0;left:0`' on side panel. This will attach the side panel to the top left corner and when user will open it with toggle button, this will show above the other content.

for resizable effect you can read : [jqueryui resizable](https://jqueryui.com/resizable/)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to understand your problem to the best of my abilities, and as much as I could, here's my potential solution to it.

The key here is `resize: horizontal`

Make 2 sections, sidebar and content.
Let the content be as it is, and try applying the following styles to the sidebar

```
min-width: 0;
height: 100%;
overflow: scroll;
position: fixed;
width: 20%;
resize: horizontal;
```

This will make the sidebar attached to the screen all time, scrollable, resizable and fill the window height. (if 100% is messing up try 100vh).

This will give you a layout like the one in this fiddle.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

#a {
  background: red;
  min-width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: fixed;
  width: 20%;
  resize: horizontal;
}

#b {
  background: blue;
  height: 500vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
```